# Prove this number must be a prime number or 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Show that if the smallest prime factor $p$ of the positive integer
$n$ exceeds $\sqrt[3]{n}$, then $\frac{n}{p}$ must be prime or 1.

I'm stuck trying to prove this. I tried this using contradiction, but I haven't been able to prove it.

My approach:

Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of the positive integer $n$.

Let $p > \sqrt[3]{n}$

Then we must show that $\frac{n}{p}$ is either a prime number or 1.

We know that $n = pe$ for some $e \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, $\frac{n}{p} = e$

We also know that $p$ > $\sqrt[3]{n}$, so $p^3 > n$, and $p^2 > \frac{n}{p}$

So, assume $\frac{n}{p} = e$ is not prime nor 1, meaning it's a composite number. Let's try to get a contradiction.

If $\frac{n}{p}$ is composite, then $\exists a,b \neq 1: \frac{n}{p} = ab $

Now, here's where I get stuck. What can I do with this info? $\frac{n}{p} = ab $ and $p^2 > \frac{n}{p}$.

Comment: If $n/p$ were neither prime nor $1$, $n$ would have at least three (not necessarily distinct) prime factors. Since $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$, what relation between $p$ and $\sqrt[3]{n}$ is there then?

Comment: But 4 is neither prime nor 1, and it does not have 3 prime factors.

Comment: No, but the smallest prime divisor of $4$ is $2$, and $4/2$ is a prime number.

Comment: I know it works for 4. But there's not necessarily 3 prime factors, as @DanielFischer said. What I want is a general proof. I don't see a contradiction. There's something I must be missing.

Comment: **If** $n/p$ is neither prime nor $1$, then $n/p$ has at least two prime factors (not necessarily distinct), and therefore $n$ has at least $3$ prime factors.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, now I think I understand. $n$ has at least 3 prime factors, as $a$ and $b$ must have at least one each, and with $p$ there would be at least 3.

Comment: Right. And since $p$ is the smallest prime factor, what do you know about the relation between $p$ and $a$ resp. $p$ and $b$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer is this right? Looking at $\frac{n}{p}$ alone and saying that it is composite. We can find a contradiction. Since .$\frac{n}{p}$ is composite we write $\frac{n}{p}=a.b$ for any positive$\frac{n}{p}$ integer $a$ and $b$. But since $\frac{n}{p}$ is also rational, then $n$ and $p$ have no common factors, thus a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer $n = pab$, $p$ is the smallest prime, so $p \leq a$ and $\leq b$. Then p would have to be less than $\sqrt[3]{n}$. A contradiction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the condition "smallest factor". 
The smallest factor of $n=p^{m} \; {p_1}^{m_1} \; \cdots$ is necessarily $p$.
Consider as you did that 
$$
n = pab\quad \left| \begin{gathered}
  p < a \hfill \\
  p < b \hfill \\
  p < ab < p^{\,2}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
then the conditions aside leads to the contradiction $p^2<ab<p^2$.
So you cannot have two terms following $p$, it must be
$$
n = pa\quad \left| {p < a < p^{\,2} } \right.
$$
and $a$ cannot decompose in primes lower than $p$, otherwise
$p$ will not be smallest, and cannot decompose in two primes higher than $p$.
Hence $a$ must be a prime between $p$ and $p^2$.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out with Daniel's hint. Your approach made it crystal clear though. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Emil I was editing my post, and did not see *Daniel's* hint coming, sorry

Comment: In other words $m=n/p<n^{2/3}$ cannot have a prime factor $q\le m^{1/2},$ otherwise $q$ is a prime factor of $p$ with  $q\le m^{1/2}<(n^{2/3})^{1/2}=n^{1/3}<p$.  Therefore $m=1$ or $m$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

**Property :**

If the smallest prime factor $p$ of the positive integer $n$ exceeds $\sqrt[3]n$, then $\frac np$ must be prime or $1.$

**Proof :**

First of all, we consider the prime factors decomposition of $n$ :

$n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r$

where $\;r\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;$ whereas $\;p_1\leqslant p_2\leqslant p_3\leqslant\ldots\leqslant p_r\;$ are all prime numbers.

So the smallest prime factor of $\;n\;$ is $\;p=p_1\;.$

Now we will prove that $\;r\geqslant3\;$ leads to a contradiction.

If $\;r\geqslant3\;,\;$ we get that

$p>\sqrt[3]n\;\;$ implies $\;\;p_1^3=p^3>n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r\geqslant p_1^3\;\;$ that is $\;\;p_1^3>p_1^3\;\;$ which is a contradiction.

Hence $\;r=1\;$ or $\;r=2\;.$

If $\;r=1\;,\;$ then $\;\dfrac np=\dfrac{p_1}p=1\;.$

If $\;r=2\;,\;$ then $\;\dfrac np=\dfrac{p_1\cdot p_2}p=p_2\;$ is prime.

Consequently ,

$\dfrac np\;$ must be prime or $1.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\frac{n}{p}$ is different from $1$ and is not prime.
So $\frac{n}{p}=a\cdot b$ with $a,b>1$.

Note that $a,b > \sqrt[3]{n}$, otherwise you have a factor of $n$ smaller or equals to $\sqrt[3]{n}$.

That implies $n=a\cdot b\cdot p > \sqrt[3]{n} \cdot \sqrt[3]{n} \cdot \sqrt[3]{n} > n$, which is an absurd.

Answer (score 1):

If $n/p$ is composite, then $n$ is the product of at least three primes, one of which must be less than or equal to $\sqrt[3]n$. So if the smallest prime divisor of $n$ is greater than $\sqrt[3]n$, then $n/p$ cannot be composite, so it's either a prime or $1$.